# Multitone-duotone conversion to RGB

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion, duotone, jpeg

I'm using photoshop and I want to export some multitone-duotone file (.psb) to rgb jpeg. But I cannot convert it from Multitone to RGB without a radical change in my colors. (see the image below)

I tried to test different color profile (in Edition > Colors...), but it seems to change nothing.

Also here is the tone panel in both image.

I'm using this color mode because It is aim to screen printing. I want to convert it to share it before printing.

(ps: file seem really compressed)

[image: Multitone tone panel]
[image: RGB tone panel]

[image: The Multitone Image]
[image: The RGB Image here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method.

1. Assuming you have a multichannel .psb already saved, open it in Photoshop, and  *Select all* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and then *Copy* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Close the image file without saving. This is just to get the document size for the next step.
2. Do *File > New*, choose the *Clipboard* size option. Set the colour mode to RGB. Click *Create*. A new blank document will open, which will be the same size as the multichannel image.
3. Click and drag the .psb file onto the RGB document's canvas, and hit Enter to confirm the place. Now you will have a Multichannel PSB smart object placed inside an RGB image file.
4. Save as JPG/PNG etc.

I tested this on a multichannel psb, and it works. There's no visible colour change.

In newer Photoshop CC versions, another possibility is to simply open the PSB and use the  new *Export As* feature, which seems to work too.

Comment: Thanks it worked !  Note that you also need to put all your channel into **direct tone mode** (when double clicking your channel in the tone panel)